# Accessing LinkedServer properties via SQL Server SMO API

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, powershell, smo

I have a powershell script to iterate through a list of LinkedServer objects in a SQL Server with some code like this:

```
foreach($linkedServer in $instance.LinkedServers)
{       
... some code ...
}
```

I want to find out information on the default security of a linked server. To see what I mean, load SQL Server Management Studio and open a linked server. If you don't have any, just create one to a remote server. Click on the Security tab and you will see a list of linked server login mappings (LinkedServerLogins collection in SMO). At the bottom of the screen will be a default setting in the section called "For a login not defined in the list above...". I cannot find anywhere in the SMO object model to get to this information. Is it possible?

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be in the [linked server login properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.sqlsmoobject.properties.aspx):

```
foreach($linkedServer in $instance.LinkedServers)
{   
    "LinkedServer:" + $linkedServer.Name

    foreach($linkedServerLogin in $linkedServer.LinkedServerLogins)
    {
        " LinkedServerLogin:" + $linkedServerLogin.Name
        foreach($property in $linkedServerLogin.Properties)
        {
            "  Property:" + $property.Name + " - " + $property.Value
        }
    }
}
```

`Impersonate` and `RemoteUser` are included in the properties.

Comment: That does work but it also returns all linked server mappings. If I test the LinkedServerLogin.Name for an empty string - this seems to be the setting I need. The SMO model is still broken in this area, I believe.